# Install fails: "Storage engine MEMORY is disabled (Table creation is disallowed)"

Tags: magento2, database, installation, server-setup

When installing Magento 2 (with `magento setup:install), I receive the following error:

```
...
[Progress: 16 / 557]
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Installing schema... 

  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                                                                                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3161 Storage engine MEMORY is disabled (Table creation is disallowed)., query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp` (  
    `parent_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parent ID' ,                                                                                                                                      
    `child_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Child ID' ,                                                                                                                                        
    `customer_group_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group ID' ,                                                                                                                 
    `website_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website ID' ,                                                                                                                               
    `price` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'Price' ,                                                                                                                                                 
    `tier_price` decimal(12,4) NULL COMMENT 'Tier Price' ,                                                                                                                                       
    PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`, `child_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`)                                                                                                                     
  ) COMMENT='Catalog Product Price Indexer Config Option Aggregate Temp Table' ENGINE=MEMORY charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci                                                                



  [PDOException]                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3161 Storage engine MEMORY is disabled (Table creation is disallowed).
```

This appears to be because [Alibaba Cloud has the `MEMORY` MySQL storage engine disabled](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26125.htm).

Is there any way to set all table creations to use InnoDB?

Comment: I think your database user has no permission to create table. recheck this and try again

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I'm using the root user and other tables created with InnoDB are created successfully. Only the tables with memory engine fail to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Magento 2 source code there are [multiple files that use `ENGINE_MEMORY`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ENGINE_MEMORY&type=). In order to work around this I had to ensure that tables are created with the InnoDB engine.

The simplest way to do this was to replace all occurrences of `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::ENGINE_MEMORY` with `'INNODB'`. This can be achieved with the following `find` and `sed` command:

```
find vendor/magento/ -name '*.php' -exec \
sed -i 's|\\Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql::ENGINE_MEMORY|'\''INNODB'\''|g' {} \;
```